# Which substance cools faster a glass bottle or the liquid inside it?

Tags: thermodynamics, home-experiment, thermal-conductivity

I had an argument with a friend who says that the temperature of the glass of a beer decreases faster than the liquid inside. for example if there's a beer bottle in the fridge for 10 minutes the glass would reach a lower temperature quicker than the liquid inside.

I don't agree to this because the collisions between air molecules inside fridge and bottle are far less than between the liquid and the bottle,so there should be a "better equilibrium" between liquid and glass in the sense that they stay almost at the same temperature. I think this is associated with another phenomena because glass is pretty dense so one wouldn't be able to tell the difference between 8 degrees and 4 degrees precisely if one does't have a right instrument it would both just seem "cold". So who's right?

Comment: I realize there might be difficulties because the bottle is ofc also standing on some floor and this might be the main part of the cooling effect and also the type of liquid, the thickness of the glass might play a big role, the temperature of the bottle before it was put in, it might also play a factor at which stage of the cooling process it is etc.. But maybe there is something general that can be said about it - maybe some bounds for realistic situations - without doing an experiment.

Comment: The cooling takes place by heat conduction, from the outside first (the glass bottle), and then from the liquid on the inside to the cooler glass and air on the outside.

Comment: update: by using the formula $Q=-\kappa \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} $ with a simple model where i just average together all the thermal conductivities and heat capacities and the experience that it takes about 5 hours for a bottle of beer to cool from room temperature to normal i get a temperature difference between liquid and glass on the order of $10^{-2}K$. can't  do the experiment to confirm though because I don't have a thermometer for this.

Comment: If you do it using the transient heat conduction equation (since the process is transient), rather than the steady state equation, you find that the temperature of the glass cools much more rapidly than the beer, with substantially greater temperature difference than 0.01 C.

Comment: @ChetMiller yeah thanks for pointing that out. In my model I assume that all there exists is a 1mm difference between liquid and glas and that the liquid and glass respectively stay at a uniform temperature throughout, also I lump these two materials into one kind of average material. Furthermore I made a conceptual mistake which when fixed would bring the difference down to the order of $10^{-3}K$, which does seem very small. Is there a simple equation or concept for the transient heat conduction you mention? I can't find it on Wikipedia.

Comment: Actually, I found it by following this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGdrmr4Uz7Y) and I get the following formula for the temperature difference water/glass by solving for glass/air and water/glass and plugging the solution of one into the other $e^{(-0.036t)}(20-20e^{(-0.0002t)})$. this has a maximum at $0.04K$ roughly 1-2order of magnitudes higher than the previous model but this seems more exact. Also the general shape is interesting. first it goes up to a maximum but then exponentially falls off for longer times.

Comment: Also I had to modify the formula they use in the lecture because they seem to assume that the enviornment is completely filled with air to interact with but in reality it's much less so I had to use a kind of "effective surface area" dividing the glass/air surface by $10^{(4)}$ and water/glass by $10$ works well but the general shape should stay the same and the maximum shouldn't go much higher than what it is there.i fitted these factors by my experience that it takes 5hours for the whole beer to cool and that the density of water to air~$10^{3}$

Comment: I have no idea what you did.  And looking at the link, the guy did not explain things well, in my judgment.  Please write out what you did so we can all see.l. The temperature at any location does not pass through a maximum with time in this problem, and for much of the time, the average temperature of the liquid is much higher than the average temperature of the glass.

Comment: @ChetMiller No, you misunderstand...  the equation evaluate the temperature difference between glass/water at a moment in time. The approximation he uses in the video is only valid for small biot-number though, which I dont think is the case here but a better approximation would involve a double infinite summation of multiple bessel functions which I don't necessarily want to get into here. I basically just looked up all the heat transfer cnst etc. and solved first for glass/air and then plugged that into glass/water giving me the temperature difference between glass/water at a moment in time.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're both saying something that's right :

Your friend : The bottle will be at a lower temperature than the liquid.

You : There is likely to be a smaller temperature difference between the bottle and the liquid than between the air and the bottle.

I think you're approaching the air/bottle/liquid system from a different angle (or drawing a line at a different place).

There will be heat transfer - at different rates - across both boundaries until air/bottle/liquid system thermal equilibrium, when the air, the bottle and the liquid are at the same temperature. Until then, the air will be colder than the bottle, and the bottle will be colder than the liquid.

Quantifying those different rates will involve accurate measurement of the initial temperatures and the temperatures after ten minutes. Ideally you'd get into differential equations as transfer rates will vary with the temperature difference, which will vary over time. Personally, I'd just drink the beer.

Comment: Yeah I figured it would just boil down to 'do the experiment' but I just can't imagine that the temperature difference would be so large to be "tasteable".

Comment: Probaly not tasteable - but then you're adding the room outside the fridge and the tongue (also depends whose tongue) to the air/bottle/liquid system. Two more heat transfer coefficients, with temperature differences variable over time. Anyhow, have one for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I had an argument with a friend who says that the temperature of the
> glass of a beer decreases faster than the liquid inside. for example
> if there's a beer bottle in the fridge for 10 minutes the glass would
> reach a lower temperature quicker than the liquid inside.

Until equilibrium is reached, parts of the bottle will be colder than the liquid.

Keep in mind that in order to cool the liquid heat must pass from the liquid through the glass and to the frig. There will initially be a temperature gradient across the thickness of the glass with the side of the glass facing the air in the frig being at the lower temperature of the gradient and the surface of the liquid contacting the glass at the upper temperature of the gradient. This means that prior to equilibrium, portions of the glass near the outer surface will be cooler than the portions of the liquid near the inner surface of the glass.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The heat capacity of the glass is much lower than that of the beer inside. so when both are subjected to a low temperature, the temperature of the glass will drop faster than that of the beer.

Furthermore, most of the heat content of the beer has to make its way out through the glass, which is in direct contact with the cold air inside the fridge. We then expect that the glass will be colder than the beer, until the beer has given up most of its heat.